# Divide and Conquer - Minimum Coins - Return Coins as Array

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Below is a brute-force solution to the minimum coin change problem. It takes an int change, which is the change that needs made, and an array of coin denominations. It returns the minimum coins needed to make that change.

How can I modify this to also return an array of the coins?

For example, if asked to give change for 10 cents with the values[1, 2, 5], it should return 2 coins min and an array [0, 0, 2] for two nickels.

```
def recMC(coinValueList,change):
    minCoins = change
    if change in coinValueList:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in [c for c in coinValueList if c <= change]:
            numCoins = 1 + recMC(coinValueList,change-i)
        if numCoins < minCoins:
            minCoins = numCoins
     return minCoins

print(recMC([1,5,10,25],63))
```

Comment: For me it looks like a task from some problem-solving website ([example](https://www.codewars.com/kata/knapsack-part-1-the-greedy-solution)), Do you expect us to write code for you?
What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Like any recursive function, you start with your *guard condition* - the test that tells you when you're done:

```
if change in coinValueList:
    return 1
```

To convert this to a list of coins, just return a list made up of 1 coin:

```
if change in coinValueList:
    return [ change ]
```

In the other part of your function, you know that your recursive calls will return a list. So, just take the list and make it a bigger list:

```
        numCoins = 1 + recMC(coinValueList,change-i)
```

becomes:

```
        coins = [ i ] + recMC(coinValueList, change - i)
```

You'll have to update your other tests as well.